# How to initialize an array before referencing it Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Why is it that when I create arr, an array then try to populate it with integers using a for-in loop it, gives me an error when I don't initialize it. From what I can tell it is initialized when I write "var arr," but obviously not so what does writing var arr actually do if not initialize it.

Error Example

```
var arr : [Int] //Error Message: Variable 'arr' passed by reference before being initialized
for i in 1...10 {
    arr += [i]
}
arr //Error Message: Variable 'arr' used before being initialized
```

Working Example

```
var arr : [Int] = [] //Allocating memory?
for i in 1...10 {
    arr += [i]
}
arr
```

Comment: That is because the array was not initialized.  You should initialize all the variables before use it.  If you put an `!` after `[Int]` I think you shouldn't receive that message.

Comment: I get the following error instead. `'[Int]!' is not identical to 'UInt8'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just saying `var arr` does not initialize your array.  Should the initial value be an empty array?  Should it have `N` copies of a given value?  If it is declared to hold type `A` objects, should it be initialized with subtypes of `A`.

So you provide an initial value; the simplest is `[]` - an empty array.

Comment: Does that mean that not initializing your variables is a bad practice?

Comment: All variables need to be initialized either as part of their declaration or in the class's `init()` method.  The compiler enforces this and thus it is worse than 'bad practice' it is illegal Swift.

Comment: @GoZoner All non-optional instance variables, you mean.

Comment: Right.  Optionals are a special case.  Thanks.